# Sequence of functions in $L^1(\Omega)$ that converge in the $L^1$ norm to $f$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

Assume $(f_n)_n$ is a sequence of functions with values in $L^1(\Omega)$ that converges in the $L^1$ norm to $f$, that is $(f_n)_n \in L^1(\Omega)^{\mathbb{N}}$, $f_n \rightarrow f$ in $L^1(\Omega)$ with $\Omega$ with finite measure. Then we can easily show that the limit is in $L^1(\Omega)$ in this way (norms are the $L^1(\Omega)$-norm):

$$|| f || = ||f + f_n - f_n|| \le ||f_n - f|| + ||f_n|| $$

now taking the limit as $n \rightarrow \infty$  we get $$ || f || \le lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} {||f_n||} $$
and since $||f_n|| < \infty$ for every $n$, we get our conclusion that $f \in L^1(\Omega)$.

My question is if my proof is correct and, mostly, what is the topological conclusion we can draw. The statement above reminds me the definition of closed set for metric spaces. So, what can we infer about the set of $L^1(\Omega)$ functions? That it is a closed subset of which space of functions endowed with the $L^1$ norm topology? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your proof is correct, but you should say that $\sup_n \|f_n\| < \infty$ since $(f_n)_n$ is a convergent sequence.

Comment: Doesn't this come directly from the fact that the sequence of $f_n$ is converging in norm to $f$ and the definition of convergence?

Comment: @Kaio-sama Well I think you have to be a little careful if you work with the definition of convergence because then you would use something like  $\|f_n\| < \epsilon +\|f\|$ for your favorite epsilon, but since you don't know that $\|f\| < \infty$ this might be problematic. But you can use that $(f_n)_n$ is a Cauchy sequence and Cauchy sequences are bounded.

Comment: $(f_n)_n$ is not a priori convergent in $L^1(\Omega)$ since we don't know that $f \in L^1(\Omega)$, it is better to say that $(f_n)_n$ is a Cauchy sequence so it is bounded.

Comment: @mechanodroid I agree. With convergent, I simply meant that $\|f_n- f\| \to 0$ and then the Cauchy sequence condition is obvious from the triangle inequality (see also my previous comment).

Comment: True, but since $L^1(\Omega)$ is complete under the $L^1$ norm, then the Cauchy sequence is convergent and the result holds, right?

Comment: @Kaio-sama. I think so, then $(f_n)_n$ is Cauchy, so there is some $g \in L^1$ such that $\|f_n -g \| \to 0$. Then $\|f-g\| \le \|f-f_n\| + \|f_n-g\| \to 0$ so $f=g$ in $L^1$.